# Automatic formatting of URLs in text input

Tags: url, links

I would like to validate links inputted by the client, so that if they enter www.somesite.com it needs to convert it to http://www.somesite.com

I know that there is an option in the channel preferences to "Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links". However, I need to be able to add class names and attributes to the anchor tags which I don't think is possible if I use this option?

How to achieve this?

(there should really be a new type of field just for URLs..)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most relevant info I can find through Google is this post from 7 years ago: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/83535/#441375

Am I still going to have to use this kind of nonsense in 2015...?

Comment: This is what addons are for. Have you looked? Quick search result shows promising right away: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/forms-js-validation

Comment: OK, this might do the job, thank you, investigating now...

Comment: Er, sorry, have you used this addon? If you could advise on how to integrate it with the publish page it would be appreciated... this is the extent of the documentation: http://reinos.nl/expressionengine/forms-js-validation/docs/publish-page I've installed and applied to the channel, but nothing happening...

Comment: No clue. Might be abandonware for all I know. Look around on devot-ee. Here's another promising looking one: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-url-extension

Comment: Funny note saying 'deprecated no not install' in the extensions panel, however installed it anyway and it works like a charm! very neat. Many thanks for you help, it is much appreciated.